# save current git state of a repo

Tags: git

I need to store the current state of a git repo. Later I need to return to the state.

The saved state should contain the current branch and changes to it.

Example:

1. I am on branch `master` and have modified foo.py.
2. save state
3. modify the repo: example: checkout other branch.
4. return to state: switch to master and revert modified foo.py

AFAIK `stash` or a temporary branch won't help here, since the branch name gets not saved.

I can live with plumbing commands, since the save-and-restore will be done in a script.

Comment: Why won't stash do this?

Comment: This is exactly what the stash was made for

Comment: Make another clone? Then you can do whatever you like and guarantee the original clone is as you left it. On the other hand I would just make a temporary commit of foo on a work branch, switch away to other stuff and then switch back to my work branch when I am done with other stuff. You can always reset the branch git reset HEAD~1 when you resume working to completly restore the state.

Comment: I updated the question: git stash does not save the branch name. That's why I ask this question.

Answer (score 6):

Using `git stash` *will* save state: it makes two<sup>1</sup> commits that are not "on" any branch (they're found via the special `refs/stash` name instead), containing the state of your index, and the state of your working tree.  It then uses `git reset --hard` to get rid of any working tree and index changes, making it safe to change branches.

The one piece of state that `stash` does not save is the name of the branch, if any, that you were on at the time the stash was saved.

To save that, you need to run `git symbolic-ref HEAD` (use `--short` to get a branch name, and note that it exits nonzero if `HEAD` is not a symbolic ref, i.e., is currently "detached"; in this case you may need to save the current commit ID somewhere, probably in a reference so as to protect it).

Note that `git stash save` will do nothing if there is no state to save, so it's wise to verify that `refs/stash` exists and points to a new and different commit-ID after the `git stash save` step.  (This is not too difficult to do in a script: use `git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash` to get the new commit ID, and use it before the `save` to get the old one.  As with `git symbolic-ref` it will exit nonzero if the reference does not exist.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Or, three commits if you use `git stash save -u` or `git stash save -a`.  The third commit contains files git normally leaves alone: untracked and ignored files.  See the [`git stash` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) for details.

Comment: thank you, you understood my question and the solution looks good.